# Program not working?

Tags: java, date

The question is to find the number of days between two dates.example-input-26/3/2000 and 12/8/2014.the output will be the no of days in between these two dates.
There is an error saying "identifier expected" and i=1 is highlighted.Also I am not sure whether the program is completely correct.

```
import java.util.*;  
class yearst
{  

    int a[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30}; 

    int i,s,s1,s2,s3,k,diy,m,m1,m2,d1,d2,y1,y2,y;

    i=1;s1=0;s2=0;s3=0;diy=365;


      void leap(int y)
        {
        if(y%4==0 && y%100!=0 || y%400==0) //for leap year
        {
            a[2]=29;
            diy=366;
        }
         else
         { 
            a[2]=28;
            diy=365;

        }
        }


        public static void main(String args[])
        {
        Scanner ob=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the months,dates and years");
        m1=ob.nextInt();
        m2=ob.nextInt();
        d1=ob.nextInt();
        d2=ob.nextInt();
        y1=ob.nextInt();
        y2=ob.nextInt();
        for(i=y1;i<y2;i++)
        {
            ob.leap(i+1)
            m=1*diy;
            s1=s1+m;
        }

        for(i=1;i<m1;i++)//no of days left in y1
        {
            ob.leap(y1);
            s2+=a[i];
        }
        s2+=d1;
        k=diy-s2;
        for(i=1;i<m2;i++)//no of days passed
        {
          ob.leap(y2);
          s3+=a[i];
        }
        s3+=d2;
        s=s1+s2+s3;
        System.out.println("No of days in between"+s)
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is a bunch of errors. First, you are calling class variables in main method without declaring them static or initializing them in constructor. Second, you are calling leap() which is method of a class from object of Scanner. It is not possible. The program will never compile nor run this way. I have modified your code to make it compilable and runnable. But one thing is for sure. Its logic is incorrect. It is giving wrong output as you want to calculate number of days between two dates. That is your job. I removed its errors. Now it is running. Here you are :-

```
import java.util.*;  
class yearst
{  

    static int a[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30}; 

    static int i=1,s,s1=0,s2=0,s3=0,k,diy=365,m,m1,m2,d1,d2,y1,y2,y;

     static void leap(int y)
        {
        if(y%4==0 && y%100!=0 || y%400==0) //for leap year
        {
            a[2]=29;
            diy=366;
        }
         else
         { 
            a[2]=28;
            diy=365;

        }
        }


        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            //i=1;s1=0;s2=0;s3=0;diy=365;

        Scanner ob=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the months,dates and years");
        m1=ob.nextInt();
        m2=ob.nextInt();
        d1=ob.nextInt();
        d2=ob.nextInt();
        y1=ob.nextInt();
        y2=ob.nextInt();
        for(i=y1;i<y2;i++)
        {
            leap(i+1);
            m=1*diy;
            s1=s1+m;
        }

        for(i=1;i<m1;i++)//no of days left in y1
        {
            leap(y1);
            s2+=a[i];
        }
        s2+=d1;
        k=diy-s2;
        for(i=1;i<m2;i++)//no of days passed
        {
          leap(y2);
          s3+=a[i];
        }
        s3+=d2;
        s=s1+s2+s3;
        System.out.println("No of days in between"+s);
    }
}
```

All the Best :)

Answer (score 0):

Only declarations and static blocks allowed out of the methods. The below executable statement must be either in static block or in constructor

```
int i=1,s1=0,s2=0,s3=0,diy=365;
```

So, I recommend you move above code to constructor.

```
yearst(){
  i=1;s1=0;s2=0;s3=0;diy=365;
}
```

Comment: I have done that but now the error is that  "m1=ob.nextInt();- non static variable m1 can't be referenced from a static context".

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You'll need to initialize your variables inside a constructor, as initializing inside a class isn't allowed
2. Have you checked out the `Date` class in Java? It might be more useful for this case.
3. According to convention, class names should start with a capital letter